# Is there a way to extract all record of a table with same column value calculating sum of another column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to rails and I have a table called Orders. Inside I have these records.

```
#<Order id: 1, amount: 12, number:"1234">, 
#<Order id: 2, amount: 19, number:"1234">, 
#<Order id: 3, amount: 23, number:"1234">,  
#<Order id: 4, amount: 12, number:"13233">
```

I want to extract all orders that have the same number attribute, into one record, that for amount attribute will have the sum of all respective amounts of the records extracted.

How can this be done on rails?

Answer (score 1):

This will return a Hash with number column as key and their respective summed amount as value.

```
 Order.group(:number).sum(:amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by below way

1. Find All Order whose number is like "1234"

   orders = Order.where(number: "1234")
2. Select the only amount from it

   orders.pluck(:amount).sum

You will get sum of all amounts

Comment: thank you for your response but I want to return an ActiveRecord that will have the amount attribute contain the sum